# maskToBounds set to NO doesn't seems effective

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, layer, shadow

I'm new to Obj-C development and I'm currently stuck on a simple issue. I'm trying to create an `NSView` and add a border and a shadow, I have this code:

```
_view.wantsLayer = YES;
CALayer *layer = _view.layer;

layer.masksToBounds = NO;
layer.borderWidth = 2;
layer.shadowColor = [[NSColor blackColor] CGColor];
layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2, -2);
layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
layer.shadowRadius = 6;
```

Obviously, this should work because I've set `maskToBounds` to `NO`, but I can't get something better than this:

[image: freaking shadow]

See? The shadow can't go outside the box. Did I miss something? I've checked many topics about this subject but I can't find anything to resolve this...

Comment: Are you sure your parent view's bounds are big enough to display outset shadow?

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but: how can I check that? The parent view is the window view, here are the properties: http://i.imgur.com/jOuwoMs.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the hosting view clips the layer to it's bounds.

You can try to enable layer backing on it's super view:

```
[_view superview].wantsLayer = YES;
CALayer *layer = _view.layer;

layer.masksToBounds = NO;
layer.borderWidth = 2;
layer.shadowColor = [[NSColor blackColor] CGColor];
layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2, -2);
layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
layer.shadowRadius = 6;
```

Given that the superview is large enough, this should also draw the portion of the Core Animation layer that lies outside of the view bounds.

[image]

Comment: Great that it worked. 
If the answer solved your problem, please check accept my answer. (Using the green checkmark below the vote button)